# How to count totals of data in a column using v-simple-table based on a criteria in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to do this with vuetify?

I'm trying to count values (from a library table) on a v-simple-table based on a criteria, here's an example:

```
Name    |  D1   |   D2   |
----------------------------
Person 1|  OFF  | 8A5P   |
----------------------------
Person 2| 8A5P  | FL     |
----------------------------
Person 3| 7A4P  | VL     |
----------------------------
TOTAL:    2     | 1
(Count how many there are in a column where the value is not OFF,FL,VL per D1, D2 column)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Vuetify cannot do the thing you mentioned here. You should use JavaScript. But you surely can iterate each cell and count them according to your needs.

Comment: @ManiMirjavadi Thanks! As expected, I just pushed the json data to an array and counted it.